# Diskless Workstation:kernel panic on boot

Tags: boot, server, kernel, dhcp, nfs

I'm trying to make a diskless workstation environment based on ubuntu server 1604

DEVICE:

```
pc1: ubuntu server 1604 ->diskless server
pc2: ubuntu server 1604 ->for diskless filesystem,kernel and initrd.img
pc3: diskless,network boot->pxe client
```

tutorial:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

I finished most steps including isc-dhcp-server,nfs-kernel-server,tftpd-hpa.

When the pxe client booting :

```
1 pxelinux.0 loaded
2 vmlinuz--4.4.0-31-generic loaded OK
3 initrd.img--4.4.0-31-generic loaded OK
```

then [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ai4P.jpg)

pxelinux.cfg/default:

```
DEFAULT 1604
LABEL 1604
KERNEL vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
APPEND root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=18.18.227.249:/nfsroot/ubuntuserver1604   initrd=initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic ip=manual rw
```

/nfsroot/ubuntuserver1604/etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/xvda1 during installation
#UUID=89909776-88ec-40cc-adb5-6db1c322a3f9 /               ext4        errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/xvda5 during installation
#UUID=73a6056d-c4cf-4634-a3be-f224cecbe64c none            swap    sw              0       0
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
/dev/nfs/  /    nfs     defaults        1       1
none            /tmp            tmpfs   defaults        0       0
none            /var/run        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
none            /var/lock       tmpfs   defaults        0       0
none            /var/tmp        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
```

Comment: It seems to me, that ifconfig couldn't find a network interface (so it fails to detect it). Could you add more info about the hardware you have ? you may try desktop live CD to check `lspci` or you may try out another USB external network interface.